# jQuery array parameter and each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm new in jQuery world, still learning. I'm trying to understand how can I pass an array parameter reading data from an "each()" loop. Let my try to explain (my native language is Portuguese, sorry).

My original code is below:

```
$('#relatorio').DataTable({
   (...)
   columns: [
      {visible:$('#c1').is(':checked')},
      {visible:$('#c2').is(':checked')},
      {visible:$('#c3').is(':checked')}
   ]
});
```

Since I'll use this in several places (reports), I did a .JS file. But, in each report, I'll have different checkboxes. So I want to scan each checkbox and mount the object array dynamically. I've add a class "colsel" in each checkbox, so I can do:

```
var vCada=[];
$('.colsel').each(function(){ vCada.push({visible:$(this).is(':checked')}); });
```

Ok, but now I don't know how to replace this directly in there.

I had success creating a function that returns the object array:

```
function StatusCols() {
  var vCada=[];
  $('.colsel').each(function(){ vCada.push({visible:$(this).is(':checked')}); });
  return vCada;
}
```

and then:

```
columns: StatusCols()
```

But I'm not satisfied with this and my newbie knowledge is not helping me :(

I've tried:

```
columns: function() {
   var vCada=[];
   $('.colsel').each(function(){ vCada.push({visible:$(this).is(':checked')}); });
   return vCada;
 }
```

So, where is my mistake? Can anyone help me (and teach me)?

Thank you!

Comment: *"But I'm not satisfied with this"* Why? The mistake at the end is that you are assigning a function to `columns`, instead of *calling* the function and assign its return value. I don't see how the last solution would be any improvement over the original code though.

Comment: You can try this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=10UX0xpP but `columns: StatusCols()` is fine.

Comment: Hi Felix, my previous code works, but need an extra function. I'm trying to remove the additional function, so my idea was create a "local" function that could return an array.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've found your exact issue just by looking, but one helpful tip; if you want to make another array that's based on the contents of a first array, it's handy to use `.map(`. It works similarly to `each`, but...well, look it up here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Blex! Works! But I really cannot understand what you did!

Comment: Instead of each you could use map to make the array. A bit neater.

Comment: @Arvy Let's say you have a function called `myFunc`. `myFunc` is equal to `function(){...}`. You call it by typing its name + a set of parenthesis: `myFunc()`. Well, it's equivalent to calling it directly (replace the name by the function declaration itself): `function(){...}()`

Comment: Thank you Katana and Quentin about "map", too.

Comment: Great @blex, never realized this. Thank you for the tip, professor :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @blex. Solved. Solution:

```
columns: function() {
   var vCada=[];
   $('.colsel').each(function(){ vCada.push({visible:$(this).is':checked')}); });
   return vCada;
 }()
```

Means: function(){...}()